# Listing ForeignKey associated instances within template (queryset within a queryset)

Tags: python, django

I have a site which catalogs local hikes, and users can log that they have been on the hike. I have a search page which contains the hikes, and one of the fields I'm trying to display is a list of all the people who have been on the hike. I've got this figured out within the individual detail page of the hike, but can't figure out how to create a new queryset within the queryset which is printing the hikes, in order to display this info on a search page.

Here's some code:

models.py:

```
class Hike(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    ...

class UserLog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hike = models.ForeignKey(Hike, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py:

```
def hike_list(request):
    qs = Hike.objects.all()
    ... some other filters here
?-->users = UserLog.objects.filter(id=qs.id)
```

template:

```
{% for qs in qs %}
{{ hike.name }}{{ hike.other_details_and_stuff }}
?----> {% for users in hikes %}{{ user.name }}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here's the working code within the individual hike's detail page:

views.py:

```
def hike_detail (request, slug)
    users = UserLog.objects.filter(hike__slug=slug)
```

How do I call on the slug from each individual item in the queryset, then run a queryset on that?

Comment: I don't see a `climb` or `slug` field. So you want all users associated with any of the hikes in the `qs` query set?

Comment: Woops, sorry. That's supposed to be hike, not climb. I'll edit the original. But yes, I want all the users associated with that specific hike in the qs queryset.

Comment: What about my other question? It is not obvious to me what exactly you are trying to query?

Comment: Yea sorry I edited the comment. So when I return a list of each Hike using a queryset, I want to be able to also list all of the Users associated with that hike (associated via the UserLog model foreignkey relationship).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to add a `ManyToManyField` to `Hike`:

```
class Hike(models.Model):
    ...
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='app.UserLog')
```

If you have no extra fields in `UserLog`, you can even remove the `UserLog` model and the `through` parameter alltogether. In the template you can do:

```
{% for hike in qs %}
  {{ hike.name }}{{ hike.other_details_and_stuff }}
  {% for user in hike.users.all %}{{ user.name }}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In order avoid too many queries, you should prefetch the users in the `Hike` query in the view:

```
qs = Hike.objects.all().prefetch_related('users')
```

Without the `ManyToManyField`, you could add a property and user the same template, but the prefetch clause could not be used that easily:

```
class Hike(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def users(self):
        return User.objects.filter(userlog__hike=self)
```

Comment: This returns an error that UserLog is not defined. Presumably because the Hike model is listed first in my models.py. If I switch the order, I get an error that Hike is not defined. And yes, unfortunately I do have other fields in my UserLog model, so can't get rid of it.

Comment: Updated. Just use the `'app_name.model_name'` notation for the through. This will also require a new migration, btw.

Comment: Still no luck, unfortunately. I've added that all in and have migrated, but still nothing. When I go into shell and fetch a hike, then try to call on the "users" field, I get the following: <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x000001C9E40EAB70>

Comment: Yeah, it is a related manager, you get the related user queryset via `hike.users.all()` as I pointed out in the template ;)